# can't include standalone runtime to my project

Tags: halide

I generated the standalone runtime that I could use with several compiled AOT functions that don't contain runtime but when I try to include it in linker it doesn't work because the file itself is of File type.

I compiled the runtime by using

```
Halide::Target t(Halide::Target::Windows, Halide::Target::Arch::X86, 64);

Halide::compile_standalone_runtime("HalideRuntime", t);
```

the computer I'm on has Windows 7 that's 64bit.

Is this a bug or am I compiling the runtime wrong?

Answer (score 0):

> it doesn't work because the file itself is of File type.

I don't understand what this means.

Comment: it means it has no extension and as far as I tried there's no way to include that